# Does spark structured streaming job fails if dependency jars are updated?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

If I update a jar which is being used in a running structured streaming job, will this running job fail ?

Comment: And, any other insights here?

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

> When using spark-submit, the application jar along with any jars
> included with the --jars option will be automatically transferred to
> the cluster.

then the current invocation cannot fail.